# Does nuclear binding energy concern nuclear force or EM force?

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, binding-energy, strong-force

From my understanding, binding energy is the energy required to separate all nucleons in a nucleus an infinite distance away from each other. I cannot tell whether this ignored the effect of one of the mentioned forces, or a combination.

After fission of a large nucleus, we know the decay products are more stable. However, they have less protons and total nucleons. This means the nuclear force holding each together is less(which decreases binding energy). The EM force pushing out may or not be less, there are less total protons, but they are closer together, which with inverse square law considered, it is not obvious to me which will win over, and why we can say  with confidence that EM force dictates the energy changes as it is much weaker than nuclear force.

Bearing this in mind, binding energy must increase when a large fissionable nucleus splits into two more stable nuclei. If this is the case, then do we assume the change in EM >> change in nuclear force and say that EM force has definitely decreased(since em would act to push nucleons apart)? Does this lead to the explanation why atoms become less stable either side of iron? In other words, elements lower than iron, the protons are very close together, so coulomb force is extremely large, despite a small amount of charge. In elements greater than iron, the amount of charge is so large to create a large coulomb force, despite the protons being relatively far away from each other.

Comment: Have you looked at the semi-empirical binding energy formula?

Comment: @RobJeffries Looks very involved. Was hoping for a qualitative explanation.

Comment: @jamie It's not that bad, the formula is lengthy but each term has a pretty simple meaning, which is explained quite well on Wikipedia.

Comment: ... and you only need to look at the first 3 terms to answer your question.

Comment: The Bethe-Weizsacker SEMF *is* the qualitative explanation.